# document.forms[i] code works in the page but gives "undefined" error in  Greasemonkey

Tags: javascript, forms, greasemonkey

So there is a page with about 50 forms.

The first form is a search, so I skip that form.

The remaining 49, I care about.

Out of those 49, I am only looking for forms with the go value equal to renew.

I wrote the code in scratch pad and it works fine.

I paste it into Greasemonkey and I get `"document.forms[i].go is undefined"`

Here is my code:

```
var i=1 ;
var total = document.forms.length -1;
while (i<=total) {

    var go_val = document.forms[i].go.value;
    if(go_val == "renew"){
        document.forms[i].setAttribute('target','_blank');
    }

    i++;
}
```

I have also tried this, to check if the go element exists and the form generates no errors, but does not run `setattribute`.

```
var i=0 ;
var total = document.forms.length -1;
while (i<=total) {
    if(document.forms[i].go){
    var go_val = document.forms[i].go.value;
    if(go_val == "renew"){
        document.forms[i].setAttribute('target','_blank');
    }
    }
    i++;
}
```

Why does it work in scratch pad, but not in Greasemonkey?

Comment: Any particular reason you're not indenting your code?

Comment: You sure this is the running code ? `(i<=total)>` extra  `>` should be removed..

Comment: something got screwed up when copying the code. i corrected it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found: ["Pitfall #3: Named Forms and Form Elements"](http://commons.oreilly.com/wiki/index.php/Greasemonkey_Hacks/Getting_Started#Pitfall_.233%3a_Named_Forms_and_Form_Elements) and figured it out...

```
var i=0;
var total = document.forms.length -1;
while (i<=total) {
    var form = document.forms[i];
    if(form.elements.namedItem("go")){
        var input = form.elements.namedItem("go");
        var go_val = input.value;

        if(go_val == "renew"){
            document.forms[i].setAttribute('target','_blank');
        }
    }
    i++;
}
```